# VS Code: Do you trust the authors of the files in this folder?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just launched VS Code 1.57 and see this message: "Do you trust the authors of the files in this folder?"

[image: Do you trust message]

Why am I seeing this message?

Should I trust the current workspace?

Comment: you can click the [our docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspace-trust) link, which explains the feature in detail

Comment: None of the docs on MS website seem to explain how the node_modules folder is handled with the Workspace Trust feature. Most projects contain open-source code, so are we to run the parent folder in an untrusted state? or is the node_modules folder excluded? Is there a way to restrict trust on a subfolder, such as the node_modules folder?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

### Background

Visual Studio Code 1.57 introduces the concept of [trusted workspaces](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspace-trust). Trusted workspaces try to make it clear that while simply browsing through code is safe, enabling all editor features in a folder/project that came from a malicious source could potentially put you in danger.

The prompt is shown when you open a new folder for the first time. Here Visual Studio Code is asking if it should be trusted or not:

- If you select `No, I don't trust the authors`, Visual Studio Code will open the workspace in 'restricted mode'. This is the default for all new workspaces. It lets you safely browse through code but disables some editor feature, including debugging, tasks, and many extensions. However, keep in mind that 'restricted mode' is all you need for many use cases.
- If you select `Yes, I trust the authors`, Visual Studio Code will trust the current workspace and enable all of the editor feature you are used to in it.

You can easily change your choice later on too.

#### So should I trust this workspace or not?

Ultimately you will need to decide for yourself if you are comfortable trusting a workspace or not. Here are a few general guidelines:

**Stick with restricted mode if:**

- You just need to quickly read some code.
- You got the workspace from an unfamiliar/untrusted source (such as that random zip someone posted on a sketchy forum)

**Consider trusting the workspace if:**

- You trust the source of the workspace and know how code ends up in your workspace
- And you also need all the features of Visual Studio Code, such as debugging

## What if I change my mind?

Say you start in restricted mode, but later realize that you now need to use the debugger (and you are confident in where the contents of the workspace came from). To switch to trusted mode, you can:

- Click on the `restricted mode` entry in the status bar

  [image: 'Restricted mode' status bar entry]
- Run the `Workspaces: Manage Workspace Trust` command in the command palette

This will open a new editor that lets you manage trust of the current workspace:

[image: Trusted workspace manager]

Select `Trust` to switch into a trusted workspace

### Can I disable trusted workspaces?

Yes, but keep in mind that doing so comes with security tradeoffs. Here are a few options:

**Using a single trusted folder to hold your projects**

If you work with many projects that you trust and don't want to be prompted about trusting each one individually, you can consider trusting their parent folder.

1. Run the `Workspaces: Manage Workspace Trust` command
2. Scroll down to the `Trusted folders and workspaces` section and click `Add Folder`
3. Select the parent folder of all your trusted workspaces

Now any project you open under the parent folder will be trusted automatically.

**Disabling the trusted workspaces entirely**

If you really want to disable trusted workspaces entirely, you can use the `Security › Workspace › Trust: Enabled` setting.

```json
"security.workspace.trust.enabled": false
```

Comment: It is a shame this feature is buggy and not only forgets your past choice, but also has no concept of the fact you created the project before the feature came to be.

Comment: The right path is: Settings > User > Security > Workspace
Trust: Enabled - uncheck
Trust: Startup Prompt - never

Comment: Feature is nice but the UI notification that shows up right in your face is annoying. UX should be paid more attention to and improved for this.

Comment: That is truly an awful UI.  The bolded text "enabled" makes it seem as if this feature is always enabled.  If you toggle the associated checkbox and have multiple windows open you will rapidly pass through each window as a new "YOU NEED TO RESTART VSCODE" warning comes up for every single window.

Comment: If you have feedback about the feature, please [open an issue against VS Code itself](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new/choose)

Comment: Thank you for showing how to disable this feature. That pop-up is EXTREMELY annoying and makes doing simple tasks like resolving merge conflicts or opening other projects tedious, unnecessarily.

Comment: Wow, what a disastrous update. Single-handedly destroyed my trust in VSCode not to mess up basic things. After a succession of confusing and unexpected dialogs and information bars, and then claiming my installation is corrupt.

Comment: You know what, this was a major security update that was extremely needed. I thought up a few different ways that a nefarious person could have sneakily got malicious code onto your machine via github repositories, and extensions. I am not certain if they would have worked, I obviously did not try to get my self arrested, but I couldn't help to keep thinking about those vulnerabilities. This last update took care of any worries I had, and I haven't paid 1 damn dollar for my favorite IDE/Editor that I have ever used, and I have paid for the entire JetBrains suite, because that use to be the

Comment: best. You know what, this was a major security update that was extremely needed. I thought up a few different ways that a nefarious person could have sneakily got malicious code onto your machine via github repositories, and extensions. I am not certain if they would have worked, I obviously did not try to get my self arrested, but I couldn't help to keep thinking about those vulnerabilities. This last update took care of any worries I had, and I haven't paid 1 damn dollar for my favorite IDE/Editor that I have ever used, and I have paid for the entire JetBrains suite,

Comment: because that use to be the best. The last thing I would ever complain about is a corrupt extension due to an update, when VS Code has continually released ridiculously awesome updates, nearly every month now, for the last couple years. Great Job VSCode team, and thank you for the Extra Security, it helps me to sleep at night!  __They need to create a comment DV button for times like these__

Answer (score 4):

Windows10 / VScode 1.64.2:

1 Navigate to user settings by paste: **%APPDATA%\Code\User**

---

2 in the `settings.json` add there:

```
"security.workspace.trust.startupPrompt": "never",
"security.workspace.trust.enabled": false,
"security.workspace.trust.banner": "never",
"security.workspace.trust.emptyWindow": false
```