# Is it normal for Visual Studio Code to ask if you trust the authors of this workspace?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it normal for Visual Studio Code to ask if you trust the authors of this workspace?

I am working in my own workspace and there is nothing in that directory why then.

Comment: This was added in the last update.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VS Code: Do you trust the authors of the files in this folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67914668/vs-code-do-you-trust-the-authors-of-the-files-in-this-folder)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is normal.

In the latest update of Visual Studio Code, every time you open a new folder Visual Studio Code asks you if you trust the owner. If yes, everything will go normally. If not, it enters a strict mode and there will be some limitations. Check out this documentation about workplace trust: *[Workspace Trust](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_57#_workspace-trust)*